# Materia UI simple select not saving selection

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I have a simple select field in a dialog form in Material UI. The form uses state to save values in a state onChange. My state code is as follows:

```
    const [planner, setPlanner] = useState({
  name: '',
  title: '1',
 
});

const { title, name } = planner;
const onChange = (e) => {
  setPlanner({ ...planner, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
```

My Form code is as follows:

```
<Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby='form-dialog-title'
    >
      <DialogTitle id='form-dialog-title'>Add New Planner</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText>
          some text
        </DialogContentText>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel id='title-label'>Title</InputLabel>
          <Select labelId='title' id='title' value={title} onChange={onChange}>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Mr</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Mrs</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        <TextField
          margin='dense'
          id='name'
          label='Name'
          type='text'
          value={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          fullWidth
          autoComplete='name'
        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose} color='primary'>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={onSubmit} color='primary'>
          Add Planner
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
```

Thank you for your help!
The full page code is as follows: It uses redux state manager and useEffect, useState Hooks. Other than that the form is very simple and everything works fine in it except for this Title dropdown.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  addPlanner,
  clearErrors,
  clearAdd,
} from '../../actions/plannerActions';
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alertActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(10),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(20),
  },
  textfield: {
    width: '100%',
    border: 0,
  },
  formControl: {
    minWidth: 120,
  },
}));
const PlannerForm = ({
  addPlanner,
  error,
  clearErrors,
  setAlert,
  open,
  handleClose,
  add,
}) => {
  // const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [planner, setPlanner] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    title: '',
    company: '',
    phone: '',
    comments: '',
    password: '123123',
  });

  const { title, name, email, company, phone, comments } = planner;
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setPlanner({ ...planner, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };
  const clearForm = () => {
    setPlanner({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      title: '',
      company: '',
      phone: '',
      comments: '',
      password: '123123',
    });
    clearAdd();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      setAlert(error.errors[0].msg, 'error');
    } else if (add) {
      setAlert('Planner Added', 'success');
      clearForm();
    }
  }, [error, add]);

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    addPlanner(planner);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby='form-dialog-title'
    >
      <DialogTitle id='form-dialog-title'>Add New Planner</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText>
          To add a new planner insert their info and they will receive an email
          to activate their account, set a new password and login.
        </DialogContentText>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel id='title-label'>Title</InputLabel>
          <Select labelId='title' id='title' value={title} onChange={onChange}>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Mr</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Mrs</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        <TextField
          margin='dense'
          id='name'
          label='Name'
          type='text'
          value={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          fullWidth
          autoComplete='name'
        />

        <TextField
          margin='dense'
          id='company'
          label='Company'
          type='text'
          value={company}
          onChange={onChange}
          fullWidth
          autoComplete='company'
        />
        <TextField
          margin='dense'
          id='email'
          label='Email Address'
          type='email'
          value={email}
          onChange={onChange}
          fullWidth
          autoComplete='email'
        />
        <TextField
          margin='dense'
          id='phone'
          label='Phone Number'
          type='tel'
          value={phone}
          onChange={onChange}
          fullWidth
          autoComplete='tel'
        />
        <TextField
          placeholder='Additional Comments'
          multiline
          rows={4}
          margin='dense'
          id='comments'
          value={comments}
          onChange={onChange}
          fullWidth
        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose} color='primary'>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={onSubmit} color='primary'>
          Add Planner
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

PlannerForm.propTypes = {
  addPlanner: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.object,
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  clearErrors: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  handleClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  add: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.planners.isAuthenticated,
  error: state.planners.error,
  add: state.planners.add,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  addPlanner,
  clearErrors,
  setAlert,
})(PlannerForm);
```

Comment: May you provide the full source code of the dialog component?

Comment: I provided the full code.

Comment: @gdh have answered your question..

Comment: still didnt solve the issue of using MenuItem Component

Comment: I solved this by adding name prop to the `Select` Thank you very much for your help. @gdh and @arthur-rubens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a name prop to the `Select`. For some reason event.target.id was not working (maybe conflicting with other wrapping components)

Here is a [working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-flower-7uqrj?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

See [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props)

> The id of the wrapper element or the select element when native.

The id is applied to the wrapper div and not to the select. To make it work, use `native` prop to `Select` and set it as true.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-select-issue-fix-9pphc?file=/demo.js)

**Code snippet**

```js
export default function FormDialog() {
  const [planner, setPlanner] = useState({
    name: "",
    title: "10"
  });

  const { title, name } = planner;
  const onChange = (e, b) => {
    const target = e.target;
    setPlanner(prev => ({ ...prev, [target.id]: target.value }));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={true}
        // onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Add New Planner</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>some text</DialogContentText>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel id="title-label">Title</InputLabel>
            <Select
              native
              labelId="title"
              id="title"
              value={title}
              onChange={onChange}
            >
              <option value={10}>Mr</option>
              <option value={20}>Mrs</option>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>

          <TextField
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="Name"
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={onChange}
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="name"
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button color="primary">Cancel</Button>
          <Button color="primary">Add Planner</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding native and then changing the MenuItem into 
` <option value={10}>Mr</option>
            <option value={20}>Mrs</option>`
worked. But that made it a simple drop down without the nice style explained by Material UI docs here:
[link]https://material-ui.com/components/selects/